# jQuery - Is it possible to disable or stop a user from clicking on a <div> element

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

Is it possible to disable a div element using jQuery. I have a click event on it and there is a radio button inside of it. This is so there is a bigger clickable area. So the user can click the radio button or the div element itself.

I have many of these types of elements. I only want the user to click one button at a time as the page refreshes when they do. In this time the user can click on other buttons and confuse the script, returning nothing or making the page go blank when it re-loads. That is why I require a disable on the div element. I know inputs and form elements can be disabled. That is why it is easy to solve the problem on the radio button itself.

I have tried:

```
   $('#element').unbind('click');
   $('#element').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault; }
   $('#element').click(function() { return false; }
```

and other various things.

Anyone have some better ideas?

Comment: place an overlay over the entire webpage, preventing the user from interacting with the webpage.

Comment: Isn't this what `<label>`s are for? You can associate them with your input controls and it effectively gives you a larger click surface (clicking the label focuses or toggles your input element). You can style the `<label>` however you see fit.

Comment: Why do you think `e.preventDefault;` or `return false` is not good enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1. Overlay method

Overlay the content with an overlay element, for example, HTML:

```
<div id="element">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    Whatever content is underneath.
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#element {position:relative}
.overlay {bottom:0; left:0; position:absolute; right:0; top:0}
```

Optionally, add a semi-transparent background to `.overlay` to make it apparent the element does not accept user input.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ9JG/).

### 2. Disable input elements

If you're just trying to disable input tags, add the `disabled` property:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
```

### 3. CSS: pointer-events

Disable clicks through CSS by setting `pointer-events:none`. Browser support is limited! See [caniuse.com/pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events). CSS code:

```
#element {pointer-events:none}
```

### 4. CSS: user-select

If you're just trying to prevent text selection, try `user-select:none`. CSS:

```
#element {user-select:none}
```

For this CSS property, all browsers need a prefixed version at this point. See [caniuse.com/user-select-none](http://caniuse.com/user-select-none).

### 5. Disable events through JavaScript

As stated in your question, you can use JavaScript (or jQuery in your case) to prevent default events from firing. This is actually a valid answer too for most common click events.

```
$("#element")
    .off("click")
    .click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
```

Depending on the element, this **will** prevent a link from being followed, a form from being submitted, a checkbox from being checked, et cetera. By using `.off("click")` it also disables any JavaScript triggers you had hooked onto the `click` event earlier.

### Final thought: let your users know what's up

Please don't just disable an element without some visual cue. You'll confuse users if they're suddenly unable to click certain elements. Try making content semi-transparent, or add a "wait" cursor icon for example.

Good luck!

Comment: Meh, whas typing the `pointer-events: none` method. But i think that's the way to go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmnzE/) +1

Comment: Well if it's just about form elements, we might as well write `<input type="checkbox" disabled />` or use the overlay method, especially if we need compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

remove the click event from the dive and add it to the specific element that should carry it.

I think the way you have done it is not specific enough.